# git: checkout files creating sub-directory

Tags: git

I am trying to copy files in the `public` directory from `master` branch to my `gh-pages` branch:

```
$ for f in `git ls-tree --name-only master:public`; do git checkout master -- public/$f; done
```

The problem with this is it creates the `public` sub-directory with all my files in the `gh-pages` branch. I want just the files themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you want to use `git show master:public/$f > $f` instead of `git checkout ...`?